# JavaScript Text Editor

Tags: javascript, html, text-editor

I am creating a JavaScript text editor, and I am having some issues with inserting my cursor with in a line that has a tab character. When the user clicks on the page I take in the x location of the click event then divide by the width of the characters (I am using a mono type font) so I can get the position that the cursor should go. My problem is: if the line starts off with a tab my cursor gets inserted multiple characters to the right of where the click event took place. Does any one have an idea on how I should be handling this?

Comment: what are you using as the editor? contentEditable element, textarea?

Comment: i use a text area to gather the input from the key board. I then insert the data into a div. I found that the contentEditable attribute did not support functionality that I needed.